# The network path was not found eroor after publishing mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have been deploying and publishing my application for quite a bit now and everytime it worked fine.

Now I published it again (no error, warnings, ..) and updated my SQL database tables like I do everytime but I get the error: [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]. No suggestion where the code fails or what so ever, only the error.

My connectionstrings in Web.config are adjusted to the SQL server.

I searched the web for this one, but found no working solution.
Does some one have experience with this error?